# How can refer a theme from other folder and make directory path to other theme in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm new in Wordpress and i have few qustions. I research on the internet, but i don't find the proper answer.

Firstly, exist one way to get URL to reference theme?

And the second questions, how can make a directory path to reference theme?

Thanks for answer and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Template URI**

To get the current active theme's directory URI, use `get_template_directory_uri()`. For example:

```
<?php
$directory_uri = get_template_directory_uri();

$my_file = $directory_uri . '/images/path/to/img.jpg';
```

See official documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/).

**Template PATH**

To get current active theme's directory PATH, use `get_template_directory()`.

```
<?php
$directory_path = get_template_directory();

$my_file = $directory_path . '/images/path/to/img.jpg';
```

Official documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/).

**Difference between theme and template**

Do note that both the function will return URI or path of the active template, meaning, if you use a child theme, then the parent theme's URL or PATH will be returned. If it is not a child theme, then simply the URL or PATH of the current theme will be returned.

If you are using a child theme and want to get the references of current child theme, then use [get_stylesheet_directory_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) and [get_stylesheet_directory](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory/) instead.

**Getting values for any theme**

If your theme is not the active one, then you will need to use [get_theme_root_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_root_uri/) and [get_theme_root](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_root/) instead.